# How to revive (get new and better answer to) an older but not outdated question that has old outdated answers?

Tags: discussion

There are questions that are still interesting but have only old outdated answers, that give the impression that there **must** be some other solutions already there, but that are not posted anymore on that question because it was answered and an old answer was set as definitive.

If I ask them they are already asked and my new question is bound to be a duplicate of the older one.

An example: [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/129891/47206). I stumble upon this, but there are many many like that.

What should I do?

Ask again?

(On that issue I already [did](https://askubuntu.com/q/537184/47206).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting a bounty for updated answers is something I have seen done. It's one of the stock reasons for offering a bounty:[image]

(I have a posted a bounty on it. Let's see what happens.)

Comment: a new answer to that question was posted, but also the question was voted for closing. how does one see the reason for a close vote?